# Building package glib:x64-osx failed with: BUILD_FAILED

Tags: gtk, vcpkg

I am trying to install GTK on my Mac (running Catalina) using `vcpkg`.

I get the following error message on running `./vcpkg install gtk`

How can I fix this?

> Error: Building package glib:x64-osx failed with: BUILD_FAILED
>
> Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
>   submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
>     Package: glib:x64-osx
>     Vcpkg version: 2019.09.12-unknownhash
>
> Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.

**EDIT**

I used `--keep-going` while running the install command, and it installed all the packages that do not require `glib` to build.

I've added the log file outputs:

[config-x64-osx-dbg-out.log](https://textuploader.com/1kpkf)

[config-x64-osx-dbg-err.log](https://textuploader.com/1kpkn)

[CMakeOutput.log](https://textuploader.com/1kpke)

Comment: Post here the error messages that you see in the log files

Comment: I have added the log file outputs